# How bad is the health of this Hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I Check every month for my HDDs health and this week I found this:

[image]

[image]

I already backed up all its contents, but is there any way to fix it?

Could re-partitioning the disk solve the problem - excluding the damaged part?

Comment: "I already backed up all its contents, but is there any way to fix it?" - Nope;  The HDD has bad sectors, in my experience, if you have more then 1 bad sectors it's time to replace the HDD.  Given you can get HDDs that are 3-5 years, I just replace my HDDs, under warranty when this happens.

Comment: Can re-partitioning solved the problem?  No absolutely not.  It can hide the problem, that is all it can do.  Hiding it would prevent data loss(on that partition, but it can not solve a hardware issue like controller failure.   Considering a 2tb hdd is $60, I wouldn't waste my time with that.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid rather exclude bad sectors on the HDD, you can use MHDD. Enclosed is a link in Polish http://forum.pclab.pl/topic/256595-Tutorial-Zerowanie-dysku-krok-po-kroku-przy-u%C5%BCyciu-MHDD/

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  But note that SU is an English-only site, so even with a working link, this is not a useful answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I already backed up all its contents, but is there any way to fix it?

Yes, only for Current Pending Sectors assuming there are enough free sectors (and ignoring the warning signs of a failing drive).

> Could re-partitioning the disk solve the problem - excluding the damaged part?

No.

The damaged sectors are automatically reallocated by the drive itself when data is written to those locations. The easiest method is just to write data to the entire drive. You may have to do it a couple times.

**Warning: this destroys all data on the drive**

### Method 1 - HD Tune Pro

Select the Erase tab, and erase the drive with zeros.

### Method 2 - Format with command line

Run `cmd` as administrator.

```
format e: /fs:NTFS /p:1
```

Note: replace "e:" with the correct drive letter.